# Fragment not creating when screen is locked

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to create fragment if screen is locked. My fragment is not creating (no one of method like `onCreateView`,`onViewCreated` , etc is called), when screen is locked. Is there some possible ways to create fragments or i need to create it after screen is on?

Everything works fine if screen is on during creating

Answer (score 0):

Fragment does not perform its lifecycle when `activity` is in background state `onPause()`.

Besides it wouldn't be encouraged to create `fragment` under background state.

You can change the timing of making `fragment` when `activity` is resumed instead.

Hope it helps :)